# Spark DF pivot error: Method pivot([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]) does not exist

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am a newbie at using Spark dataframes. I am trying to use the `pivot` method with Spark (Spark version 2.x) and running into the following error:

> Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o387.pivot. Trace:
>   py4j.Py4JException: Method pivot([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]) does not exist

Even though I have the `agg` function as `first` here, I really do not need to apply any aggregation.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
+-----+-----+----------+-----+
| name|value|      date| time|
+-----+-----+----------+-----+
|name1|100.0|2017-12-01|00:00|
|name1|255.5|2017-12-01|00:15|
|name1|333.3|2017-12-01|00:30|
```

Expected:

```
+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+
| name|      date|00:00|00:15|00:30|
+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+
|name1|2017-12-01|100.0|255.5|333.3|
```

The way I am trying:

```
df = df.groupBy(["name","date"]).pivot(pivot_col="time",values="value").agg(first("value")).show
```

What is my mistake here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `values="value"` parameter in the `pivot` function. This should be used for a list of actual values to pivot on, not a column name. From the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot):

> values – List of values that will be translated to columns in the output DataFrame.

and an example:

> ```
> df4.groupBy("year").pivot("course", ["dotNET", "Java"]).sum("earnings").collect()
> [Row(year=2012, dotNET=15000, Java=20000), Row(year=2013, dotNET=48000, Java=30000)]
> ```

For the example in the question `values` should be set to `["00:00","00:15", "00:30"]`. However, the `values` argument is often not necessary (but will make the pivot more efficient), so you can simply change to:

```
df = df.groupBy(["name","date"]).pivot("time").agg(first("value"))
```